# Create list of Java metaclasses that have common base class

Tags: java, java-7

I have several classes derived from common base class.

```
public class BaseClass ...

public class ClassA extends BaseClass ...

public class ClassB extends BaseClass ...
```

I need to store those classes in list where I can retrieve them via their index and create specific instances at runtime and I can do that with following working code:

```
    List<Class> a = new ArrayList<Class>();
    a.add(ClassA.class);
    a.add(ClassB.class);

    Class c = a.get(0);
    BaseClass m = (BaseClass) c.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

I would like to know if there is any way I can tell that any class in that list has to be descendant of `BaseClass`. I want to ensure that only descendants of `BaseClass` can be added to the list. Something like following:

```
    List<Class<BaseClass>> a = new ArrayList<Class<BaseClass>>();
    a.add(ClassA.class);
    a.add(ClassB.class);
```

But above code throws compiler error:

```
Error:(135, 10) error: no suitable method found for add(Class<ClassA>)
method List.add(Class<BaseClass>) is not applicable
(actual argument Class<ClassA> cannot be converted to Class<BaseClass> by method invocation conversion)
method List.add(int,Class<BaseClass>) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method Collection.add(Class<BaseClass>) is not applicable
(actual argument Class<ClassA> cannot be converted to Class<BaseClass> by method invocation conversion)
```

Comment: I am not sure I get you; do you just mean this `List<Class<? extends BaseClass>>`?

Comment: @ᴳᵁᴵᴰᴼ Yes, that is the answer, if you add it as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a wildcard upper-bounded by your base class:

```
List<Class<? extends BaseClass>> a = new ArrayList<Class<? extends BaseClass>>();
```

If you declare it like in your code:

```
List<Class<BaseClass>> a = new ArrayList<Class<BaseClass>>();
```

it won't work because `Class<ClassA>` is not a subtype of `Class<BaseClass>`, even if `ClassA` extends `BaseClass`.

Demo here: http://ideone.com/SJGEIz

Answer (score 5):

`List<Class<BaseClass>>` means only the exact BaseClass.class can be used  as an element of the collection. By definition, your problem is that you want to insert subclasses:

```
List<Class<? extends BaseClass>> a = new ArrayList<Class<? extends BaseClass>>();
```

Will make sure that subclasses are allowed but no other classes.

Comment: To be entirely precise, it _means only the exact Class<BaseClass> can be used_ as an element of the collection. List<BaseClass> would happily accept a ClassA.

Comment: Thanks, as promised I have accepted other answer but you get +1